Deserializing into Dictionary<string, object> vs. working with JsonNode in .NET's System.Text.Json
I'm wondering which is more efficient (or a better practice in general):
When working with arbitrary JSON strings that you don't or can't have a model for (for whatever reason), is it better to deserialize them into Dictionary<string, object> or is it better to work with the System.Text.Json objects like JsonNode?
To make the question more specific, suppose the aim is to extract a field from a specific path in the JSON.

JSON is a hierarchical data format. So, loading a JSON document into a Dictionary<string, object> is really a dumb choice, unless you restrict yourself to JSON which is only at max 1 level deep. And then having to handle with all the complications arising from having to deserialize to object. Big oof... The real choice would be between STJ's JsonNode and JsonElement, each having their particular advantages/disadvantages. Depending on your demands, you might perhaps want to seek the help of specialized libraries (such as JsonPath.Net, for example) that might favour one over the other.

@ZippydiZip "unless you restrict yourself to JSON which is only at max 1 level deep"... you do realize that an "object" might as well be a ist or dictionary themselves, right? A map of string to object is a very common, language transcending way to represent json. Maybe not the most specialized, but certainly not dumb.

If you only need read the json (not manipulate it) JsonDocument would probably be the easiest option.

If the task is to extract  only one field value from a huge (or small) JSON and you don't care about the rest of the JSON, I would suggest to use JsonNode, since you don't have to describe the class according to the JSON structure. It would be something like var fieldVal = JsonNode.Parse(jsonString)['foo']['bar'].GetValue<T>();

Not to mention that attempting to deserialise a JSON array (e.g. [1, 2, 3]) to Dictionary<string, object> would throw an exception.
